# how to make animation like in the video in blender

Tags: animation, conversion

please help to make  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJQ6czHRiss  this animation

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *Simple Deform* modifier in its *Bend* mode, just keyframe its *Angle* value:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. please  now tell how can make animation like in this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70kBeurvp_Q

Comment: @Kebab Sharif please ask a new question and i'll answer   ;)

Comment: My dear , I would like to know how did you make this GiF/Animation  ?

Comment: You mean what app? It's called ScreenToGif, it's free  ;)

Comment: DEAR  , I TRIED TO REPLICATE  WHAT YOU SHOWED ,BUT IT DOESN'T WORK WITH OUT Origin( i hav to give an empty ) , so my asking is :why it works in your animation?

Comment: maybe apply the rotation of your plane?